# Maven won't recognise testNG annotation for files in '/src/main/java' when maven test is executed through cmd

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am facing particular issue that when I run the project as maven test in eclipse it runs fine. But when I try to execute the same in command line, build fails with errors like followings -

> //src/main/java/com/qa/util/TestUtil.java:[10,18] package org.testng
> does not exist [ERROR]
> //src/main/java/com/qa/util/TestUtil.java:[11,30] package
> org.testng.annotations does not exist [ERROR]
> //src/main/java/com/qa/util/TestUtil.java:[64,35] cannot find symbol
> [ERROR]   symbol:   class ITestContext [ERROR]   location: class
> com.eBusiness.qa.util.TestUtil

Out of curiosity I also tried moving entire /java folder under test folder but the issue remain. What is wrong in my configuration?

My TestUtil.java file:

```
package com.qa.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import com.eBusiness.qa.base.TestBase;

public class TestUtil extends TestBase{
    
    public static long PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT = 60;
    public static long IMPLICIT_WAIT = 20;  
    
    static Workbook book;
    static Sheet sheet;

    @DataProvider(name="test")
    public static Object[][] getTestData2() throws IOException { 
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Teju\\Downloads\\payrollDps.xlsx");
        sheet = book.getSheet("allowance");
        Object[][] data = new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
        int noOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        //System.out.println(noOfColumns);
        String[] Headers = new String[noOfColumns];
        for (int j=0;j<noOfColumns;j++){
            Headers[j] = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        }
            for (int a=0;a<noOfColumns;a++){
                if(Headers[a].equals("Allowance Name")){
                    for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                        data[i][a] = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(a).toString();
                        }
                 }
            }
            try {book.close();} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
          return data;
    }   
        
    @DataProvider(name="Data")
    public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(){
    return new Object[][] 
        {
            { "ATitle" , "Adesc"},
        };
    }
    
    public static void refreshPage(){
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
    
    public static void takeScreenshotAtEndOfTest() throws IOException {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");     
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(currentDir + "/screenshots/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
        
        }   
}
```

Also my pom if needed:

4.0.0

```
<groupId>HRMS</groupId>
<artifactId>eBusinessAutomation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>project</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>https://www.github.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
            defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
             <!-- This is added to create java project -->
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Attach the shade into the package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mkyong.hashing.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>code_test_run</suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Unit tests belong to `src/test/java/<package>/XClassTest.java` and the test framework should be defined with scope:test and not with `compile` scope. Also make the test class follow naming convention like `*Test.java` ...

Comment: first advice is followed. Second it was earlier scoped to test but it was throwing error even for java file in /src/test/java in eclipse run itself, so I followed  another stackoverflow advices and changed to compile which then it resolved those erros and made it eclipse executable. third is followed as well. Testutil do not have any test itself, it just have dataproviders which are required for test. So it doesn't make sense to name it as test.

Comment: Running in Eclipse is not helpful. First check should be always the plain command line... Yes ok fine to name Testutils that way but it should be put into `src/test/java` as well (it belongs to the test classes) The compile scope is simply wrong. Apart from that you should never put an absolute path in your code... that works only on a single machine...

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue and followed what [Rahul Das](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66558348/7742878) said but made a slight change; I updated the scope of the dependency to `<scope>compile</scope>`.

So finally the dependency will look like:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

That update in **scope** did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope of the dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
```

or you can try remove the scope

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.10</version>
</dependency>
```

are you placing the test classes inside the default test package, then its need to be changed to under **src** (if its a automation project)

Comment: It's not working. I tried all the solutions

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody faced same problem, take a look at the classpath of your project. It should point to the actual repository. In my case I was initially pointing it towards the eclipse project when I ran it in cmd thus it kept throwing error.